# Loading search results when user drag google map

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

How can i implement search to database when a user drag the Google map. The markers should be updated according to the search results like AirBnb. I am using CodeIgniter for backend. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the AirBnb website, it looks like their using Flight. A framework, by Twitter. Although you'll have to read up on their documentation on how to use it; http://flightjs.github.io/

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Craig but can you tell me how can i implement this with Google maps as i have also read somewhere that airbnb is using Flight. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never tried to implement this before. It looks interesting though, maybe something I will look at for a future project. View the source of the Airbnb website, and see how they do it.